# Where can I find a good Spring RESTful web service project using Google Protobuf?

Tags: spring, rest, protocol-buffers

I developed a RESTful web service using the latest *spring-boot-starter-parent 1.1.8*. I want to learn how can I use Google Protobuf in a RESTful webservice using Spring. In my project, there are 3 to 4 internal RESTful web services that interact a lot, I would like to explore Google Protobuf for transferring the objects between them.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greetings")
class HelloController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<HelloDTO> storeHello(@RequestBody HelloDTO hello);
       ...
    }
}
```

Client calls this using RestTemplate:

```
new RestTemplate().postObject("url-of-greeting-api", new HelloDTO("Hello"), HelloDTO.class);
```

HelloDTO looks like this:

```
class HelloDTO {

    private String message;

    public HelloDTO(String message) {
       this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you actually identified that the JSON serialization is a problem? It's a lot easier to work with JSON for debugging, testing, and integration with other systems than ProtoBuf.

Comment: Not really, but for learning purpose I am exploring ProtoBuf.